# What are possible causes for a theme's JS plugins to stop working, inside a MeteorJS app?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm coding in MeteorJS
I'm using a bootstrap based theme.

The dropdowns etc based on bootstrap, driven by plugin javascript code, don't work. Javascript code I write separately (to handle a login button, for example) does work.

There are no errors generated in the console at any time.

Any idea on the potential issues/how to debug this?

Comment: have you placed the theme's code in `client/compatibility/`?

Comment: no..I was hoping to avoid this by placing the entire theme within /public (accessible by the browser as the app root "/" ).
Will try the compatibility way now...

Answer (score 0):

The most commom issue by FAR is the unique way that Meteor renders pages.

A normal theme is created with a traditional load order in mind:

- a browser goes to a page and starts to parse the HTML from TOP to BOTTOM
- As it goes from top to bottom it builds the DOM nodes of the page.
- The browser loads the scripts tags that are down at the very bottom of the page, after most of the HTML code.
- 99.9% of the time these scripts at the bottom of the page require certain DOM nodes to be in existence for them to work. In the traditional top-down approach, this isn't a problem because all the relevant HTML is above these script tags.

Meteor does not have a top-down approach. If anything, it inserts sections of HTML into the page at different times, which means if you are coding in a top-down way, it's highly likely that at least some of your theme's script files get loaded before the HTML that they need to run are rendered on the page.

Your example of a login button event handling is a perfect example.

You first need the browser to parse

```
<button id="login-button"></button>
```

into a DOM node so that your accompanying event handler can work:

```
$('#login-button').click(function(){ //do something});
```

What that code is doing is first looking for something with `#login-button`, then attaching a `click` event listener to it. If `#login-button` doesn't exist by the time it runs, it has nothing to attach the listener to, and therefore your event handler won't run when the button is eventually clicked.